# Retrive all web element values without scrolling down in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to access web elements in a table column and actually there are 22 elements but only 20 are displayed when I try to locate them in the Chrome inspector or chrome console as shown in the image. Is there any way I can access it without scrolling? Because only if I scroll I am able to retrieve 22 elements. But the scrolling is not fixed either. We need to scroll down to 450 pixels only then the web elements will be shown as 22. In the future there can be 100 web elements. So where should I scroll then? [20 web elements displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FJHG.png)
I am trying to read all web elements values in the Holdings column.
If you see in another image, I scroll down and see 22 elements.
[22 web elements displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2n5C.png)

Adding code which I am trying

```
public int getSumOfHoldingsValue() {
        try {
            JavascriptUtils.verticalScrollByPixels(driver, shareHolderInputScreenHolderListViewGrid,
                    Utils.SCROLL_BY_PIXEL_MEDIUM);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int num = holdingsValue.size(), i = 0, sum = 0;
        while (i < num) {
            sum = sum + Utils.convertStringToInteger(holdingsValue.get(i).getAttribute("innerText"));
            i++;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

The num is returning only 20 without javascript scroll.

Can anyone please help me with this? How to achieve this using Selenium and Java?

Comment: Please add a minimum reproducible code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about Selenium Java or JS. But in Selenium Python, the "find_elements()" method will retrieve all of your desired web elements in the whole page, even if they are not currently visible.